# How can i separate out a git folder into a new folder in tortoisegit?

Tags: tortoisegit

How can I do a subtree with tortoise git?

from my understanding it is not supposed yet?

I want to split off a folder into a new repository though. What is the process?

Or do I just have to accept that I will have to lose the history to carve the folder out?

Answer (score 0):

Git subtree is not supported by TortoiseGit (v. 2.1.0) yet.

See https://tortoisegit/issue/2255

However, Git submodules are possible - just create a new repository, move all files into that and then add it as a submodule to your old working tree.